# jQuery Toggle Nav

Tags: jquery, toggle, nav

I'm triyng to make a toogle nav, that when I click to show more, the nav will expand from 5 to the max number of itens.

Here's the code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

  jQuery("#nav-sidebox > li > a:first-child").removeAttr("href");
  jQuery("#nav-sidebox > li > a:first-child").css("cursor", "pointer");
  jQuery("#nav-sidebox > li > ul > li:nth-child(5)").nextUntil("ul").slideToggle();

  jQuery("#nav-sidebox > li > a:first-child").click(function(){
    jQuery("#nav-sidebox > li > ul > li:nth-child(5)").nextUntil("ul").slideToggle();
  });
});
```

The 5th line makes all itens after li item 5 to toggle, but how can I do to when I click at the first a child, only this ul toggle.

Here's the HMTL:

```
<ul id="nav-sidebox">
  <li>
  <a>Click to toggle</a>
    <ul>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
  <a>Click to toggle</a>
    <ul>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this...

html (I just added text to the items so I could see what's going on)...

```
<ul id="nav-sidebox">
  <li>
  <a>Click to toggle</a>
    <ul>
      <li>1</li>
      <li>2</li>
      <li>3</li>
      <li>4</li>
      <li>5</li>
      <li>6</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
  <a>Click to toggle</a>
    <ul>
      <li>a</li>
      <li>b</li>
      <li>c</li>
      <li>d</li>
      <li>e</li>
      <li>f</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>​
```

jQuery...

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("a").css("cursor", "pointer");
  $("li:nth-child(5)").nextUntil("ul").slideToggle();

  $("a").click(function(){
      $(this).parent().find("li:nth-child(5)").nextUntil("ul").slideToggle();
  });
});​
```

You can see the results in this jsFiddle... http://jsfiddle.net/Xm8Vt/